# How to rectify price display option in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Nielsen theme & woocommerce plugin for my eshop. While adding product I have entered both Regular Price and Sale Price to the product. But Frontend displays only one price.. The strikeout price is not getting displayed..

Backend Screenshot:
[image]

Frontend Screenshot:
[image]

Both the Theme and plugin is up to date...
Is there is any way to rectify this problem??

Comment: Can you switch to another theme to verify that this is theme-specific?

Comment: If I activate Twenty Thirteen theme both the prices are getting displayed...!

Comment: So it is definitely your theme. I would first look for a `woocommerce/single-product/price.php` template and rename that so it gets ignored. Otherwise there might be something in `functions.php` that is filtering `woocommerce_get_price_html`.

Comment: Is there is anyway to get it displayed..?

Comment: As I mentioned, try renaming/removing the `price.php` template from your theme so that WooCommerce will use it's default.

Comment: I didn't found price.php template from my theme..

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible for me to pinpoint the solution as I am not familiar with that theme.

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to comment out all of `functions.php` and re-activate each function one at a time to try to isolate the problem. Or you could contact the theme authors. Or you could hire someone.